# How can i get more than 1000 parts of amazon s3 multipart upload using php-aws lib listParts() method.

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I use this code, and it returned me no more than 1000 parts of upload. How can i get more than 1000 parts of amazon s3 multipart upload using php-aws lib listParts() method? Thanks.

```
$parts = $s3->listParts(array(
            'Bucket' => $bucket,
            'Key' => $keyName,
            'UploadId' => $uploadId,
        ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are more than 1000 parts, then the result will contain the `NextPartNumberMarker` field. Take the value from `NextPartNumberMarker` and make another request, exactly like your original, but add a `PartNumberMarker` parameter with the value from `NextPartNumberMarker`, like this:

```
$result2 = $s3->listParts(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $keyName,
    'UploadId' => $uploadId,
    'PartNumberMarker' => result1['NextPartNumberMarker'],
));
```

These parameters are documented in the [API documentation for the ListParts operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_listParts).

Doing that is kind of a pain though, so the easiest way is to use the ["Iterators" feature](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/feature-iterators.html) of the SDK. Iterators enumerate one part at a time, and automatically make subsequent requests in the background for more as needed. To use the iterator for the ListParts operation, you can do something like this:

```
$parts = $s3->getIterator('ListParts', array(
    'Bucket' => $bucket,
    'Key' => $keyName,
    'UploadId' => $uploadId,
));

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    // Do something with the part data
    printf("%d: %s (%d bytes)\n", $part['PartNumber'], $part['ETag'], $part['Size']);
}
```